# Sensei Category Page not displaying courses

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

New to Sensei...

I've created 2 courses, both oof which are in a category called "california".

I then created a page called California and have added the following 2 short codes (tried the second after the first didn't work):

```
[sensei_courses category="california" orderby="name" order="asc"]
[sensei_courses category="11" orderby="name" order="asc"]
```

However my courses still aren't displaying.  Can anyone tell me what I might be doing wrong?

Thhanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried testing while running a default theme like https://wordpress.org/themes/twentysixteen/ or https://www.woocommerce.com/storefront/ (by WooCommerce, the same developers)?

Shortcodes seem to work for me on regular pages on a test site running the latest version of WordPress and Sensei, so I'm wondering if something is getting in the way.